# Change column name in a table in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Is there any way to ALTER a table and change the column name in clickhouse?
I only found to change tha table name but not for an individual column in a straight forward way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The feature has been introduced [here](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/9948) into v20.4.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME COLUMN old_name TO new_name
```

You can also rename multiple columns at on:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 
    RENAME COLUMN old_name1 TO new_name1, 
    RENAME COLUMN old_name2 TO new_name2
```

---

*Old answer:*

ClickHouse doesn't have that feature yet.

> Implementation is not trivial, because ALTERs that changing columns
>   are processed outside of usual replication queue, and adding rename
>   without reworking of ALTERs will introduce race conditions in
>   replicated tables.

https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/146#issuecomment-255631384

As @Slash said, the solution for now is to create new table and

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` SELECT * FROM `old_table`
```

---

Do not forget that column aliasing won't work there (`AS`).

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` SELECT a, b AS c, c AS b FROM `old_table`
```

That will still insert `a` into first column, `b` into second column and `c` into third column. `AS` has no effect there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use CREATE TABLE new_table with another field name 
and run INSERT INTO new_table SELECT old_field AS new_field FROM old_table

Comment: Yes I thought about that.. but it's quite an unelegant way to do it.. it's odd there isn't an inline way to do its as the name of a column is just a virtual property.. it should be quite easy to make a way to change them

Answer (score 0):

If you created the table using `Engine=log`, it won't allow you to alter or rename the column.

```
connection_string = f'clickhouse://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}' 
engine = create_engine(connection_string)      
conn = engine.connect() 
table = "table1" 
schema = 'Parameter String, Key UInt8'
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}({}) ENGINE = Log".format(table,schema))
```

If you created table using the `mergeTree` engine, it’s allowed to rename the column:

```
engine.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}({}) ENGINE =MergeTree ORDER BY Key".format(table,schema))
```